# How to make my instance access private in Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have 2 instances in google cloud engine. let say:
**a-instance** and **b-instance**, I want to make **a-instance** not have access in public but the **b-instance** can access **a-instance**. for example:

The **b-instance** want to access **a-instance** in below:

```
curl ip-external-a-instance:7713/v1/healthcheck
```

For right now, the **a-instance** still can access public. How to make **a-instance** private access?

[image: screenshot, instances]

Answer (score 1):

better remove the `external IP` from instance A and access it through it's `private IP`.

see the documentation for [Securely Connecting to VM Instances](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#bastion), below `bastion hosts`

(which would be instance B).

[image: GCE - Bastion Host]

> **tip**: always make a snapshot, before messing around with the SSHd configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create firewall rules to do something like that. If you wish for the internet to not be able to access your VM but the b-instance to do it, you should create the firewall rule only allowing b-instance to access a-instance.